# Maven build failing to find symbols and packages from JAR in local repository

Tags: java, maven

Maven appears to know about *utilities-20190520.jar* and brings it into the build, however, when code consuming is compiled, *utility-20190520.jar*'s packages and symbols cannot be found. Note that lots of other third-party JARs (stuff like *org.apache.common-io*, NiFi JARs, etc.) are got by Maven and code consumes them without error.

I have multiple modules:

```
. pipeline (parent)
+-- shared
`-- other modules
```

The parent (or super) *pom.xml* specifies this dependency for use by all submodules:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
  <artifactId>utilities</artifactId>
  <version>20190520</version>
</dependency>
```

Executing `mvn dependency:tree compile` (in parent subdirectory) I see

```
...
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ pipeline ---
[INFO] com.acme.nifi.pipeline:pipeline:pom:2.0.0
[INFO] +- com.acme:utilities:jar:20190520:compile    (my JAR)
[INFO] +- org.apache.nifi:nifi-api:jar:1.9.2:compile (NiFi JAR)
...
```

--it appears that *utilities.jar* has been got from the local repository, then it gets to compiling the first (sub)module:

```
[INFO] com.acme.nifi.pipeline:shared:jar:2.0.0
...
[INFO] +- com.acme:utilities:jar:20190520:compile    (my JAR again)
...
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/russ/sandboxes/pipeline/shared/src/main/java/com/acme/DeferringXmlParsingFilter.java:[10,33] package com.acme.xml does not exist
...
[ERROR] /home/russ/sandboxes/pipeline/shared/src/main/java/com/acme/nifi/processor/DeferringXmlParsingFilter.java:[61,70] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Tag
  location: class com.acme.nifi.processor.DeferringXmlParsingFilter
```

The compiler complains that it doesn't know package *com.acme.xml* nor *com.acme.xml.Tag*, a class in that package--this despite by all appearances that *utilities-20190520.jar* containing them is present.

I'm treating *utilities-20190520.jar* like any other JAR, it's on *~/.m2/repository*, I have a `<repository>` specification for it, *settings.xml* is set up right--indeed, lots of other JARs come in. Here's my JAR in the local repository:

```
~/.m2/repository
+-- com
    +-- acme
        +-- utilities
            +-- 20190520
                +-- utilities-20190520.jar
                +-- utilities-20190520.pom
                +-- etc.
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Sanity checks - did you `jar tvf` the utilities.jar file to make sure it contains `com/acme/xml/Tag.class`? If yes, is the utilities jar in the parent POM's `dependencies` block or `dependencyManagement`? If the latter - it needs to be in the either the parent's `dependencies` block or this project's. If both of those check out - does the pipeline project build a fat jar that is somehow not including the utilities jar on the classpath? Check the manifest perhaps?

Comment: Yes, to looking inside utilities.jar. Yes, it's in the parent's <dependencies> block rather than in <dependencyManagement>. These errors occur long before the parent/pipeline project is built. In fact, it's the first module, shared, that's being built when the errors occur. So, no intermediate JARs have been built yet.